# meteor - get value from collection serverside

Tags: meteor

I want to send an email from the current_user(client) to userY(a member) without exposing the emailaddress to the client. So all serverside.

I have the _id of userY (from the router param: email.toUser = Router.current().params._id;) and send it as a value to a method.

In the method function I want to do something like

```
var to = Meteor.users.find({ _id: email.toUser });
```

Now when I console.log(to) I get a huge _mongo object instead of the user profile (I expected to be able to log: to.profile.email) what's the best way to get the value from the email field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is the cursor to the collection set.

To retrieve the records, you can use `.fetch()`

```
var to = Meteor.users.find({ _id: email.toUser }).fetch();
console.log(to[0].profile.email);
```

As you are looking up by ID, you are expecting only 1 result, so you could also use `findOne()` instead of `find()` this will return the first element directly.

```
var to = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: email.toUser });
console.log(to.profile.email);
```

EDIT: I'd like to add that replacing `{ _id: email.toUser }` by `email.toUser` should work. When using just the ID, there is no need to pass an object.

Answer (score 3):

You should change `find` to `findOne`

Like this.

```
var to = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: email.toUser });
```

find return the whole `Mongo.Collection` cursor